Kivy , widget outside layout
enter image description hereI drew a frame in S2, it was supposed to be in S2 (i.e. on the right side, in the middle) but it appears in the lower corner, at 100, 100 of the screen
so a bit like above. the link is the home screen
Am I misattributing something?
class R(Widget):
    def __init__(self,x,y,szer,wys, kB=(1, 1, 1, 1)):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.szer=szer
        self.wys=wys
        super().__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*kB)
            Line(rectangle=(self.x,self.y,self.szer,self.wys),width=1.5)
            




Okno = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

Top = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10,size_hint=(1, .35))
F.CustomGraphics.SetBG(Top, bg_color=[0,1,0,0.2])
Top.add_widget(Label(text="aaaaa"))

Srodek = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10)  
 
S1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)
F.CustomGraphics.SetBG(S1, bg_color=[1,0,0,0.2])
S1.add_widget(Label(text="bb 11"))
Srodek.add_widget(S1)

S2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)
F.CustomGraphics.SetBG(S2, bg_color=[1,1,0,0.2])
S2.add_widget(F.R(100,100,100,100, kB=Ziel50))
Srodek.add_widget(S2)

Bottom = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10,size_hint=(1, .35))
F.CustomGraphics.SetBG(Bottom, bg_color=[0,0,1,0.2])
Bottom.add_widget(Label(text="cccc"))
            
Okno.add_widget(Top)
Okno.add_widget(Srodek)
Okno.add_widget(Bottom)

self.add_widget(Okno)

the green square should be in a different place

It looks like you are passing (100, 100, 100, 100) to the R.__init__() method, which is used in your canvas instruction to draw the Recrangle at pos (100,100) with size (100,100). And that is what you are seeing.

yes, but I thought the square would be drawn in relation to S2, not the main window. How can I change this?

See the note in this Documentation.

unfortunately I can't find the answer
